# Chrome extension- How to have your main script run every time a page loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So my main content script runs when i refresh the page however when I click on a new page of the webpage it doesnt run again; only once when I refresh the page. I want it to rerun every time the page changes or when the url changes. The main function in the main content script is called "runExtension()"

This is my background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

    alert("LOADED");
    setTimeout(runExtension, 1000);

  }
})
```

And this is my manifest.json

```js
{
 "manifest_version": 2, 
  "name": "RateMyBull",
  "description": "View professor ratings from RateMyProfessor when signing up for classes on the USF schedule planner", 
   "version": "1.0",

 "permissions": ["https://usf.collegescheduler.com/*"],
 "background": {
     "scripts":  ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["https://usf.collegescheduler.com/*"],
  "js": ["RateMyBull.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "jquery-3.3.1.js"],
  "run_at": "document_idle",
   }
   ]
}
```

Here is the main script

```js
setTimeout(runExtension, 1000);


function runExtension(){

  var tableElementNode = document.querySelectorAll(".section-detail-grid.table-bordered-wrap>tbody>tr>td>div");
  console.log(tableElementNode);


  for (var i = 0; i < tableElementNode.length; i++) {
  if(tableElementNode[i].children.length < 1 && tableElementNode[i].innerText != "Not Assigned") {
   tableElementNode[i].className = "professor";
  }
 }
 var professorsArray = [];
 var professorElementNode = document.querySelectorAll(".professor");
  for (var i = 0; i < professorElementNode.length; i++) {
   professorElementNode[i].id = i;
   var professorName = professorElementNode[i].innerText;
   professorName = professorName.trim();
   professorName = professorName.replace(/,/g, "");
   professorName = professorName.split([' ']);
   var firstName = professorName[1];
   var lastName = professorName[0];
   var professorObj = {
    first: firstName,
    last: lastName,
    ID: i
   };
   professorsArray[i] = professorObj;
   console.log(professorsArray[i].first);
 }
 alert("this just ran");
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg === 'url-update') {
        alert("TEST");
    }
});
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).

Comment: Yeah it still doesnt run my main function again

Comment: Added the main script

Answer (score 0):

[`Content scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) like `RateMyBull.js` run in a totally separate environment from the background page (on, [but somewhat isolated from](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), a webpage).

If you want your background page to cause code in a content script to run, use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple).

In your case, try changing `background.js` to:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {type: "runExtension"});

  }
})
```

And adding a listener to your `RateMyBull.js` content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type === "runExtension")
      runExtension();
  });
```

Of course, there are lots of ways a webpage can "change". See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2844565) and associated answers wOxxOm referenced in the comments for more insight on detecting various types of changes.